# How to rebuild the index of Sonatype Nexus automatically when publishing a new artifact?

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin, nexus, sonatype

I am using the [Gradle maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to push build artifacts to a [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository) machine which is running `Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.15-01`.

The deployment configuration is as follows:

```groovy
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        if (credentials.user == "deployment.fancy") {
            pom.version = project.fancy.defaultConfig.versionName
            repository(url: "https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/com.example.release") {
                authentication(userName: credentials.user, password: credentials.password)
            }
        } else {
            pom.version = project.fancy.defaultConfig.versionName + "-SNAPSHOT"
            repository(url: "https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/com.example.snapshot") {
                authentication(userName: credentials.user, password: credentials.password)
            }
        }

        pom.artifactId = "${project.artifactId}"
        pom.groupId = "com.example.libs"
        pom.project {
            description "Revision ${getVersionCode(project)}"

            organization {
                name 'Example Inc.'
                url 'https://www.example.com'
            }

            scm {
                tag "${getVersionCode(project)}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I upload an artifact it is successfully stored in the corresponding folder. I can add its dependency to a project and use it.
When I check for new versions of the artifact with the [Gradle Versions plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) however it does **not automatically detect** that there is a new version. I took a look at the *maven-metadata.xml* file and noticed that it is **outdated**:

```xml
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
    <groupId>com.exanoke.fancy.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>exanoke-fancy</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>0.6.0</latest>
        <release>0.6.0</release>
        <versions>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
            <version>0.2.2</version>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <version>0.5.0</version>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20191119124423</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

In the example version 0.7.0 and 0.8.0 are already available.

I can update the file by invoking "Rebuild index" on the folder tree as [described in the Nexus documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/configuration/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-ManagingRepositoriesandRepositoryGroups).

What can I do so the index is rebuilt automatically every time I publish an new artifact?

## Answers to comments

- I am using Gradle wrapper v.6.0.1 in the project.
- The following plugins are applied to the project:

  ```
  plugins {
      `java-gradle-plugin`
      `maven-publish`
  }

  apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
  apply(plugin = "com.github.ben-manes.versions")
  apply(plugin = "maven")
  ```

Comment: In maven repositories it is the responsibility of the publishing client to download the maven-metadata.xml files, update them, and re-publish them.  That's the way the maven deployment protocol works.  So this looks like a Gradle problem.

Comment: @rseddon Do you see any misconfiguration in my snippet? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the plugins applied in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Which Gradle version do you use? Can you perhaps provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Chriki Can you please explain how I should provide a minimal reproducible example given this issue involves a client project and a server?

Comment: Gradle provides two different plugins to publish to Maven repositories. The first one called `maven` is outdated and deprecated since version 6. Only the new one called `maven-publish` should be used. It seems like both plugins are applied in your build, but the old one is used to actually publish the artifact.

Comment: @JJD: I mean at least a _complete_ `build.gradle` file that removes the guesswork for people who try to reproduce your issue with their own Nexus installation. Without knowing your applied plugins (which were not mentioned in the question before) and other, possibly relevant configurations it’s pure luck to be able to reproduce the issue and provide a good answer.

Comment: @LukasKörfer I added `maven-publish` to project to allow local deployment. It adds the `publishToMavenLocal` and related tasks.

Comment: I suggest to run the build with the `--info` switch to get more output: `gradlew --info uploadArchives`. From what I can tell, `maven-metadata.xml` is downloaded from the Nexus repository, updated locally and then uploaded to Nexus by the Gradle build.